# How to find status and citation information about a patent application

Tags: usa, search, status, us20050015326

I'm looking for information on [US patent application 2005/0015326](http://www.google.com/patents/US20050015326).

How can I find out whether this application was granted or abandoned and in either case, whether any other patents have cited or referred to this publication.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to look for the actual information on the status of a US patent or patent application is to access the US Patent and Trademark Office's public information portal (PAIR). After searching for the patent document, which can be done in a number of ways, e.g. bu application number, publication number, and the like, information about the status can be obtained, and it is even possible to look at every document that has been exchanged between the inventor and the office.
The website of PAIR can be found at: [PAIR](http://portal.uspto.gov/external/portal/pair)

Answer (score 2):

According to [Patent Buddy](http://www.patentbuddy.com/Patent/20050015326), this patent has status **ABAN** so has been abandoned.

Also, this patent is cited in several other patents listed at [Google's patent datbase](http://www.google.com/patents/US20050015326).

Comment: But Google doesn't show it as ABAN does it?